# Problem installing AWS Cli "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python, pip, aws-cli

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.pyc', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/parser.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/parser.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.py', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/relativedelta.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/relativedelta.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/init.py', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/zoneinfo/init.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/zoneinfo/init.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo/init.pyc', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/zoneinfo/init.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/zoneinfo/init.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/zoneinfo', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/zoneinfo', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/zoneinfo'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.py', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/tz.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/tz.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/relativedelta.pyc', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/relativedelta.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/relativedelta.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.pyc', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/rrule.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/rrule.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/init.py', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/init.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/init.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/parser.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/parser.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.py', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/tzwin.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/tzwin.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/rrule.py', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/rrule.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/rrule.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/init.pyc', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/init.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/init.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.py', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/easter.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/easter.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/easter.pyc', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/easter.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/easter.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tz.pyc', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/tz.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/tz.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/tzwin.pyc', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/tzwin.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k/tzwin.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil', '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/var/folders/07/1fp6lk792lgg19769prhtfsw0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-Ivmj8k'")]

Answer (score -1):

The answer might be this one:

https://marcelog.github.io/articles/mac_osx_python_pip_install_operation_not_permitted.html

"In the specific case of using PIP to install Python packages, you can overcome this by installing everything into your own home directory with the --user flag"